# LED dashboard lamps in car issue

Tags: led

I have made a custom dash in my car using a Lenovo M8 tablet that runs Maxx Dash, the app that works with the ECU in the car (MaxxECU RACE). As this is now my only dash, I wanted to wire in some LEDs for indicators, dipped, main, handbrake, etc. so it's road legal.

All good so far.

The problem is the cel LED. I wired the LED + to a 12 V ign source and the LED - to the cel wire. Everything works fine, ign on, cel light comes on, start car, light goes out.

But that's the problem: the LED doesn't go out, not completely. It remains very dimly lit and I want it to go totally out.

So I read this [thread](https://ls1tech.com/forums/conversions-swaps/1616125-mil-light-wiring-issue.html), and the guy there says with authority to wire a 7805 between 12 V ign and the LED, but how will that work (it doesn't, I tried)?

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish what I want with the LED?

Comment: the LED is remaining dimly lit because it is receiving a tiny amount of current. you could increase the resistance between 12V and the LED to lower the current. But this would lower the "on" current as well, so you would have a slightly less bright "on" LED.

Comment: CEL is check engine light?

Comment: measure the voltage on the CEL wire with the LED connected and the  engine running normally.

Comment: What's a cel LED? what's an ign source? Using a 7805 to fix the problem sounds like nonsense to me either way, i'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes cel is check engine light, the yellow lamp that lights if there is a fault with the engine on the car. Ign is ignition, so the 12v is only active when the key is switched to on.